# How to get the x and y of canvas coordinates from a x,y,z point in the viewer. Is required for CustomToolTip of the Data Visualization extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Im trying to put a CustomToolTip to a Sprite from the Data Visualization extension. In the documentation it shows multiple examples like this one [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Mnz.gif), but I have not found the code they use to get it, or any other code example using this feature. The documentation also isn't being of a lot of help to find how to get the x and y coords.

The idea is to add a CustomToolTip with a title and description to a Sprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to get the x and y coords.

viewer.worldToClient(new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z )) with the x,y,z being the 3d coords you want to convert to the canvas 2d coords. It will give back a  THREE.Vector3 object, where z has value 0, and x,y has the desired values